# Which ingredients can be used to create Navy Dye?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

In Zelda: Breath of the Wild you can dye armor using ingredients of a certain colour. That's all fine and dandy, and I'd love to dye my armor Navy, but I don't have enough ingredients to do so. As far as I can tell, if you have less than the required materials, then the only way to figure out which materials make which dyes is by looking at the colour of ingredients.  The only problem is that I'm colour blind, so I actually have a lot of trouble determining which items are navy versus another colour (like blue or purple). I've tried looking around online for a list but I haven't had any luck.

Which ingredients can be used to create Navy Dye?

Comment: For a second I got my games crossed over Diabl 3 also has dyeing system, and you have access to them when you go to the vendor. I was very confused for a moment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Raven Dreamer said, Luminous Stone is one. However, Bladed Rhino Beetles also work, and can be found in many places, namely a tree directly right of the Plateau's opening cutscene.

Source: [Dye - Zelda Wiki](https://zelda.fandom.com/wiki/Dye)

Answer (score 5):

The only item I've found that are Navy is "Luminous Stone", which you can mine from the ore deposits that glow at night.

Given the general frustrations with the Dye interface, I've not tried much more than that.